# Swift problems with addPersistentStore: "expected type before ->"

Tags: swift, throw

I can't figure out what is wrong, can someone help me?

```
coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
let store = coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil) throws -> NSPersistentStore
```

It's saying:

> expected type before ->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this final part from your `addPersistentStore` method call:

```
throws -> NSPersistentStore
```

and ignore, for now, any exceptions thrown by this method (using a `try!` before the method call), like this:

```
let store = try! coordinator.addPersistentStore(...
```

and you should be good :)

---

By the way, the return type (and `throws` qualifier) are only needed on the *method definition*. They aren't necessary (or even allowed!) when *calling a method*.

Comment: tnx a lot) it helped